# How to wrap submit data of form in extjs 4.2?

Tags: forms, extjs, submit

I have now by submit:

```
method: save
name: Michael
birthday: 1983-02-01
```

but I need:

```
method: save
data[name]: Michael
data[birthday]: 1983-02-01
```

and field name must be like `birthday` not `data[birthday]`.

Comment: Unable to get your requirement ? To send extra data to server layer, use extraParams  in extjs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you're handling a form submission where you have a control representing the form:

```
var formData = form.getFieldValues();
```

[From Ext.form.Basic.getFieldValues](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-getFieldValues)

And then submitting via ajax:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({url: "postlocation.php", method: "POST", data: formData});
```

[From Ext.Ajax.request](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.Ajax)

If you don't want to submit your form, you can override a button on the form to invoke a process that simulates a submission.

```
// form def up here
buttons: [
    text: "Pseudo-Submit",
    id: "altsubmitbuttonthing"
]
```

In your controller (or an event handler for the button:

```
this.control({
     "button[id=altsubmitbuttonthing]": {
         click: function (control) {
             var form = control.up("form"), // <- now you have your form and you can do whatever you want with it's data.
                 formData = form.getFieldValues(),
                 preparedData = {};

             formData.theDateField = new Date(data.theDateField);
             formData.theIntField = parseInt(data.theIntField, 10);

             preparedData.data.birthday = formData.birthday;
             preparedData.data.name = formData.name;

             Ext.Ajax.request({
                 url: "/submissions",
                 method: "POST",
                 type: "json",
                 data: preparedData
             });
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas!
But this solution is not appropriate because it is necessary to use the "submitValue: false" property for fields, and independently convert the form data to string (date for example).
Maybe there is some other option? Can somehow be solved by "api"(form property)?

Comment: Don't submit your form? Sure thing.

Comment: @Constantant if this helps solve your problem would you mind throwing an upvote my way?

Comment: @Constantant check it now. If this doesn't cover your requirements then you'll need to expand what it is that you actually need to include something beyond wrapping your values inside of an object named "data" and submitting through a request back to your service.

Comment: I am just having problem that the form post submission does not work ONLY with chrome, this fiddle save me

Comment: This is an awsome solution to make cross-domain-posts with ExtJs work. Just do the Ajax-call like this: `Ext.Ajax.request({url: "postlocation.php", method: "POST", data: formData, useDefaultXhrHeader: false});`And on the server-side add the `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"`