# My site doesn't work after the update Chrome 83

Tags: google-chrome, webforms, ext.net

So, I have website on ext.net 1.7 (last version), and after updates my site doesn't works. The Chrome-console shows no errors. It's just no worked. But it worked in previous versions of Chrome. 
[WebConsoleErrors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao2xe.png)

I read about change in Chrome but found nothing the problem.
Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
(function () {
 function isChromium() {
  var isChromium = window.chrome;
  var winNav = window.navigator;
  var isIOSChrome = winNav.userAgent.match("CriOS");

  if (isIOSChrome)
   return true;
  else if (isChromium !== null && typeof isChromium !== "undefined")
   return true;
  else
   return false;
 }

 if (isChromium()) {
  Ext.override(Ext.data.Connection, {
   doFormUpload: function (o, ps, url) {
    var me = this;
    var doc = document;
    var form = Ext.getDom(o.form);
    var hiddens = [];
    var hd;

    Ext.iterate(Ext.urlDecode(ps, false), function (k, v) {
     hd = doc.createElement('input');
     Ext.fly(hd).set({
      type: 'hidden',
      value: v,
      name: k
     });
     form.appendChild(hd);
     hiddens.push(hd);
    });

    var formData = new FormData(form);

    function successCallback(data) {
     var r = {
      responseText: '',
      responseXML: null,
      argument: o.argument
     };

     if (data) {
      var match = /<textarea>(.+)<\/textarea>/i.exec(data);
      if (match != null && match.length >= 2) {
       r.responseText = match[1];
      } else {
       r.responseText = data;
      }

      r.responseXML = $.parseXML(data);
     }

     me.fireEvent("requestcomplete", me, r, o);

     function runCallback(fn, scope, args) {
      if (Ext.isFunction(fn)) {
       fn.apply(scope, args);
      }
     }

     runCallback(o.success, o.scope, [r, o]);
     runCallback(o.callback, o.scope, [o, true, r]);
    }

    $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: url,
     data: formData,
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     success: successCallback,
     error: function () {
      console.log(arguments);
     }
    });

    Ext.each(hiddens, function (h) {
     Ext.removeNode(h);
    });
   }
  })
 }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You should insert current script in body for all pages after load extjs

Comment: Could you explain what this code does and why it would fix the issue?

Comment: current script override standard behaviour for form requests https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/source/Connection.html#Ext-data-Connection

in the old version, submission was via form.submit(). In the new version of the browser, this operation is not performed immediately and can be stopped by the following request. The script submits the form and receives a response through an ajax request

Comment: Hello @НикитаДанилов!
First of all, thank you very much for the patch and the explanation.
We have just encountered this issue and your insight sheds a lot of light on the problem. Actually, many people have already got problems with Chrome 83 upgrade:)
Anyways. We use Ext.NET 4.1 and we don't really want to use jQuery additionally.
1. Do you think there is a way to get back the old Chrome behavior as a patch? 
2. Do you think Chrome team will consider it a bug and fix it by their own?

Comment: @daniil-veriga, For current case you may try replace jquery ajax request on ext.ajax.request. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273286/how-to-wrap-submit-data-of-form-in-extjs-4-2.

Also, I did not ask the development team about this breaking changes. Maybe this is a bug, but our production site cannot wait for it to be fixed

Comment: I would be grateful if someone reports this to Google Team

Comment: I believe we are already aware: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1086503&q=form&can=1

Comment: * They.
It is one more related bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1085097